# swagger array of objects not validating in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger

I have a swagger.yaml file in nodejs application given below

```
/updateuser/{userId}:
x-swagger-router-controller: User
put:
  tags:
    - User
  summary:  Update User
  description: Update User
  operationId: updateUser
  parameters:
    - name: userId
      in: path
      description: userId for which subscription needs to be updated
      type: string
      required: true
    - name: subData
      in: body
      description: Subscription To be updated
      schema:
       type: array
       items:
        $ref: "#/definitions/userDataInput"
  responses:
    "200":
      description: Success
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/Response"
    "500":
      description: Error
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"


definitions:            
 userDataInput:
 required:
  - productId
  - subscriptionId
 properties:
  productId:
    type: string
  subscriptionId:
    type: string
```

Now I'm validating subData in my user controller using nodejs module swagger-model-validator for example given below code

```
var yaml = require('js-yaml')
var fs = require('fs')
var swaggerObject
try {
swaggerObject = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync('swagger.yaml'), 'utf8')
} catch (err) {
 // Error here
}

var Validator = require('swagger-model-validator')
var validator = new Validator(swaggerObject)
var validation = validator.swagger.validateModel('subData', body, 
false, true)
if (validation.valid) {
// logic here 
} else {
// show error
}
```

User will call this API like PUT /updateuser/{userId} and body parameter
subData

```
[{
"userId": "DSHS333FHFHD",
"productId": "465454445",
},
"userId": "RYY48433FHFHD",
"productId": "435654125",
}
]
```

But the problem is, it is not validating array of objects userDataInput, I have given productId and subscriptionId required field, if I omit productId it's not giving any error and also if put some extra field for ex productId1 it's not validating also. Any help.

Comment: Which version of swagger-model-validator are you using? Btw your spec is not valid - the `userId` parameter must be `in: path`, not `in: query`.

Comment: I have corrected added in path, i'm using swagger-model-validator 2.1.0 version

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the Swagger Object you are creating.  You might be better off using the validator directly and passing in your models manually.

```js
validator.validate(object, swaggerModel, swaggerModels, allowBlankTarget, disallowExtraProperties);
```

You appear to be passing in the Swagger Definition and not the swagger client which generally has already decoded your definition.

The swaggerModel would be your subData schema section and the swaggerModels would be your definitions section.

Comment: can you mention what should be the right Swagger Object?
as i see it, using the `validator` directly misses the entire point of using the `swaggers` scalability and requires creating a `swaggerModel` for each endpoint and make sure it is up-to-date.